# ValueError at /category/ The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django, sqlite, backend, web-frontend

I am building an Ecommerce website in Django for the first time. Some how despite following the YT tutorial, I am not able to render image that are uploaded from my Django Admin Panel.
Here are my codes:

1. Models.py

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='image/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

2. Views.py

```py
def category(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {"products":products}
    return render(request,'store/category.html', context)
```

3. category.html

```html
{% for product in products %}

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="product__item">
        <div class="product__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="{{product.image.url}}">
            <div class="label new">New</div>
            <ul class="product__hover">
                <li><a href="{{product.imageURL}}" class="image-popup"><span class="arrow_expand"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_heart_alt"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="icon_bag_alt"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="product__item__text">
            <h6><a href="#">{{product.name}}</a></h6>
            <div class="rating">
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="product__price">${{product.price|floatformat:2}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

4. settings.py

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Error I get:
[image: error screenshot]

Please Help. Thank you.

I tried to render images in django by following along a Youtube Tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django shows an error when the file is not associated with the image field. While saving the object of `Product` model, make sure to add an image file to the field.
You can use the following snippet :

```
<div class="product__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="{% if product.image %}{{product.image.url}}{% endif %}">
```